# Magento force registration plugin like on zulily.com

Tags: magento, plugins, registration

where can i find or create Magento force registration plugin like on https://www.zulily.com/ with only email and password

Answer (score 1):

if have a newsletter popup extension then simply replace newsletter code with login file code and disable close popup overlay click and disable close button if you have it. and it will work like a charm. hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks bro got it :-)